# making python rock paper sissors game

Tags: python

Hey I am new to python and am making a game of rock paper scissors, how ever the condition is that the users have to select 15 options(rock,paper,scissors) which will be then played against the opponent in the order they were placed. I have made the game for a single turn but am not sure how I can code 15 attempts and then compare them to the opponents 15 attempts. Also the user is not required to attempt 15 times he can attempt less but choose to lose the times he didn't attempt. The player with the most points will win. What can I code in python to be able to make 15 attempts and compare in order of choice. Thank you a lot in advance I really need help
just to clarify I want to explain that im not really looking an answer on exactly how to do it but rather direction on what to learn and focus on such as loops and lists as i'm stuck on what to learn and where to learn it.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this question is unanswerable without seeing your code. Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Start with learning what a list is, a good start is to look through tutorials like [google developers](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/lists) or just [the examples in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques). Try something using a list of answers and update this question with that and any problems you encounter (or delete it if this answers your question).

Comment: thank you those links are useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make a `list` for both player one and player two. I'm assuming they would both be using the same computer.
Use a `loop` to add to the array, in which you take user input.
Then iterate through the lists and compare them, can be done with yet another `loop`. This could be done with a function.

```
def compare(choice_p1, choice_p2)
#logic to decide

loop:
    compare(player_one_list[x], player_two_list[x])
```

Comment: This doesn't compare the choices in order, which was the second part of the question. They're effectively asking you to write the whole game for them. Also, you'd be better using a `for` loop if you have a pre-defined number of iterations.

Comment: @roganjosh Now it does. Yeah, but I was bored and need the training. True about the for-loop.

Comment: So when the OP turns this in as homework and then asks a similar question without any attempt next week, will you also answer that as well? By simply giving the OP an answer for this problem without the OP doing any work - you are actually preventing someone from learning (homework or not) and may cause the OP to get a low score in the class when he can't finish his final project or test or if the professor/TA/teacher actually searches SO - just so you know we do.

Comment: Also that is a list not an array

Comment: @JGreenwell Changed 'array' to 'list'.

Comment: @JGreenwell I changed my answer.